# Script to Modify text

Tags: bash, awk

I have a text contain many line of text in this format:

i need to remove some text of the lines and change place of some column like this format:

```
041114 00:22:06 #146422 INFO Trying to load config
```

That is, to this format:

Note: i will do this not for just one row, but i need it to all the text file that contain many rows.

I tried to use awk like:

```
awk '{ print $2" "$3" "$5" "$9 }
```

but I didn't get what I need.

Comment: How did you expect that awk script to change `2014-11-04` into `041114`?

Comment: d=04; m:11 ; y=14
change 2014 to just 14

Comment: Do you have access to GNU sed?

Comment: You are mentioning `i will do this not for just one row, but i need it to all the text file that contain many rows`. If so, please provide a [mcve] so that we are sure the answers cover the real case you are facing.

Comment: i get this text from servers log file
it contain many rows like the example i wrote, but the numbers chnage in every row.

Comment: Why did you cripple your question with your edit revision 5, deleting the source format example and the generic destination format?

Comment: It is difficult to offer solutions when the problem statement is simply, "it doesn't work".  Please [edit] your question to give a more complete description of what you expected to happen and how that differs from the actual results.  See [ask] for hints on what makes a good explanation.

Answer (score 1):

If all the lines are that exact format, then `sed` is the best tool:

```
sed -r 's/.*\[20([0-9]{2})-([0-9]{2})-([0-9]{2})T([0-9]{2}:[0-9]{2}:[0-9]{2})\.[0-9]+ (#[0-9]+)]  ([A-Z]+) -- :/\1\2\3 \4 \5 \6/'
```

Any lines that do not match the pattern precisely will be left unchanged.

*Note: I'm using GNU sed, which is typically installed by default on Linux. Other sed implementations may vary.*

Comment: its not working with me
is there any idea to fix it with AWK?

Comment: Does it work with the line you posted? That's what I tested, so if that doesn't work there's something else wrong.

Comment: This isn't a one-liner in awk.

Comment: its working with single line.
but its not working with wrole text file

Comment: So, I'm supposed to fix that by guess work? Anyway, this isn't a scripting service. I've answered the question that was asked and given you a starting point to work from.